# Tensor products of profinite groups

Tags: commutative-algebra, profinite-groups

Let $R$ be a profinite commutative ring, and let us take two ordinary $R$-modules, $M$ and $N.$Let $M^\wedge, N^\wedge$ be the profinite completion as $R$-modules, i.e we complete with respect to the submodules such that the quotient is finite. Consider the completed tensor product $M^\wedge \hat{\otimes}_R N^\wedge.$ Is it true that $M^\wedge \hat{\otimes}_R N^\wedge \cong (M \otimes_R N)^\wedge,$ i.e that the completed tensor product commutes with profinite completion?

Comment: How are you defining the completed tensor product?

Comment: @user43687 As in : http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AMU

Comment: But then, by definition the completed tensor product is precisely the completion of the tensor product.

Comment: @user43687: Well, there is something more to show, right? Namely, one must show that the submodules of the tensor product of the form $M' \otimes_R N + M \otimes_R N'$ where $M' \subset M, N' \subset N$ has the property that $M/M',N/N'$ has finite length is cofinal in the set of submodules of the tensor product so that the quotient has finite length. But this should be true, right?

Comment: No, there they are defining a fundamental system of open submodules for the topology on the tensor product, so there is no property to verify

Comment: @user43687 I agree that the left hand side clearly has that topology. However, for the right hand side, which is a profinite completion of a tensor product (which is not profinite or has any topology) , this should be verfied. Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see why any submodule of $M \otimes_R N$ such that the quotient is finite has the form $M' \otimes_R N + M \otimes_R N'$ for submodules $M'\subset M,N' \subset N.$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65047/discussion-between-twistediso-and-user43687).